# EF Core migration issue: modifying stored procedures for table changes in .NET 7

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I am encountering an issue with EF Core migrations while working on a stored procedure utility in a .NET 7 project.

In the initial migration, I created `Table1` and the corresponding `StoredProcedure1` using code-first migration. Later, I modified `Table1` by adding two new columns `Column2`, `Column3` and adjusted `StoredProcedure1` accordingly.

`CreateBulkInjectionSP` this method is in the stored procedure utility.

**Here's the problem:** when I run the migration for stored procedures, it correctly alters `StoredProcedure1` in the utility. However, if I drop the database and rerun the migration, I get an error stating "invalid `columnA` in `StoredProcedure1`" from the initial migration.

```
 public static string CreateBulkInjectionSP()
 {
      return @"CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE InsertBulkData
                  @Data ProductDataType READONLY
               AS
               BEGIN
                   INSERT INTO Table1 ([Column1])
                       SELECT [Column1],
                       FROM @Data;
               END";
}

public partial class IntialSps : Migration
{
     protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
     {
         migrationBuilder.Sql(UserDefinedTableTypesUtility.CreateProductDataType());
     }

     protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
     { }
}
```

How can I resolve this issue and efficiently manage the creation and modification of stored procedures within migrations in .NET 7? Your insights on handling stored procedure modifications after altering related tables during migrations would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Stored procedure code should be part of migration not `UserDefinedTableTypesUtility`. You should have two versions.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv is there any other way to create or alter stored procedures other than writing in migration?

Comment: Migration files is a history of your procedures and tables transformation. Do not separate them. Also you can move SP SQL into resources, but for sure all versions.

Comment: Thank you i got your first point. can you please explain what do you mean by moving SP SQL into resources? @SvyatoslavDanyliv